# AngularJS: When should I create another controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a convention when I should create a new controller in my page?

Is it something like 1 controller per page? `PageController`

Or something like `HeaderController`, `NavigationController` and `FooterController` which is per component?

Any helpful resource will also help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a section on where to use a controller here: [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

Comment: Rule of thumb: whenever an individual element is complex enough to warrant its dedicated controller, and/or any element which is independent of other elements and can be controlled by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to create one controller for the page content, and one for each component repeated on the page (navbar, footer ...), in order to be reused on other page.

Bests practices here : https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure (see "modularize" and "components")

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything to justify my claims so just count on my 2+ years of experience in angular.

These are the cases where I would create a new controller:
1. A new view in the app.
2. A reusable piece of code (can be integrated with a directive).
3. When there's a lot of logic in a view controller I usually create 'sub-controllers' just so it becomes more lean.

Final say about controller - Angular2 & React are saying goodbye to controllers, so I'd recommend to move controller logic either to services or directives.

Cheers